Are questions about problems with DB in container on-topic?
I saw a question on SO and voted for its migration to DBA site, but now not sure if it was a right choice.  [I'm not putting a link here to avoid meta-effect].
It boils down to Oracle errors when running Oracle container in Docker.

On topic, if the question is about the database specifically.
Off topic, if the question is about the underlying container technology.
It's not always easy for the person asking the question to do this classification, so I think it's OK to still ask the question and let the community chime in.
Having now seen the question you're referring to, I have a feeling that it falls into the second category.
